# Google Sheets - add all values until last key is found

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet where I need to add all the values from last interest date till current interest date. How can I do that ?

[image]

For example, here in the above sheet I need to calculate the interest charged on *01-Feb-2021* which is sum of ***$580.15*** and ***$952.91*** (in turn it is adding all interest values until last **Interest** keyword is found in 2nd column - which is ***$1533.06***)

How do I calculate it automatically by looking at the previous and current **Interest** keywords in 2nd column.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14Fv5rjQqrp_RpvuZOyapvf4YalFk-q6JHLohdTlyBDo/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the sample sheet shared. @player0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> add all values until last key is found

try:

```
=QUERY(B3:H, "select B,sum(H) where B is not null group by B label sum(H)''")
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(LARGE((B3:B="interest")*ROW(B3:B), 2)+1, 8)&":"&
 ADDRESS(  MAX((B3:B="interest")*ROW(B3:B)), 8))))
```

[image]

Comment: I want to just add H4 and H5 (which are *Interest* values after last _Interest_ keyword till current _Interest_ keyword)

Comment: Thanks @player0 .. It is working fine. Could you please explain me the solution. Also I want to calculate interest at different points. Please see the updated sheet here. 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14Fv5rjQqrp_RpvuZOyapvf4YalFk-q6JHLohdTlyBDo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sure. if you run: `=INDEX(B3:B="interest")` it will return `TRUE/FALSE` for each row. that's basically `1/0` so we multiply this with row numbers. 0*any row number is 0 and 1*row number that in B column contains our word... (in our case row 3 and row 5) then we use `MAX` to get the highest number from this array (`5`) this will be then inserted into `ADDRESS` under row attribute and as column, we set `8` (8th column = H) this will give us raw coordinates of H5 (eg. end of our range. now to find the start of our range we use `LARGE` instead of the previous `MAX` with 2nd parameter set to `2` as

Comment: we want to get the 2nd largest number from our array (that's `3`). again we put it into `ADDRESS`. this will give us H3 so we add `+1` to our `LARGE` fx so we can get H4. at this point we have a raw range H4:H5 so we use `INDIRECT` to convert it into true range. then we use `SUM` to literary sum the constructed range H4:H5 and wrap it all into `ARRAYFORMULA` (coz multiplication of arrays requires it)

Comment: for example, if you want to find the previous sum you just use 2x `LARGE` where 1st will be looking for 3rd biggest number and 2nd `LARGE` will be looking for 2nd largest number: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(LARGE((B3:B="interest")*ROW(B3:B), 3)+1, 8)&":"&
 ADDRESS(LARGE((B3:B="interest")*ROW(B3:B), 2), 8))))`

Comment: Thanks @player0 for detailed explanation.